# Load runner throwing 406 Error while replaying script

Tags: loadrunner, http-status-code-406

While replaying the script I am getting below error message:
`Error -26625: HTTP Status-Code=406 (Not Acceptable) for "https://example.com"      [MsgId: MERR-26625]`

> 406 - Client browser does not accept the MIME type of the requested
>   page.
>
> The page you are looking for cannot be opened by your browser because
>   it has a file name extension that your browser does not accept.

Getting this error at below call

```
web_custom_request("bootstrap",
                   "URL=https://<Domain Information>",
                   "Method=POST",
                   "Resource=0",
                   "RecContentType=application/json",
                   "Referer=https://<Domain Information>",
                   "Mode=HTTP",
                   "EncType=application/json;
```

Can you please suggest how can I overcome this error.

Comment: What is the `https://<Domain Information>` exactly?

Comment: What is the **exact** URL that you are sending this to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered that you may be missing a header in your request?   Also a possibility, cookie mismanagement - Which could also be header related if you needed a cookie value in the header which was unhandled.

Comment: Issue got resolved. It caused due to missing CSRF Token Header. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for providing feedback on the resolution for future people researching this HTTP 406 issue

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well and in looking at the snapshot viewer, on the replay, I could see an error was related to a value I was posting and it needed to be unique. I added a timestamp to the body and it fixed the issue.
From:
"Body={"fileMapID":{FILEMAPID},"matchers":["Activate_MapName}"]}",
To:
"Body={"fileMapID":{FILEMAPID},"matchers":["Activate_MapName_{TS}"]}",